# TSQL transpose rows to columns based on fixed set of input values

Tags: t-sql, pivot-table

I want to transpose a table based on a limited number of input values for column `Brand`

My source:

| Id | Brand | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adidas | Type A |
| 1 | Puma | Type B |
| 2 | Adidas | Type C |
| 2 | Puma | Type D |

Desired Output:

| Id | Brand Adidas | Type Adidas | Brand Puma | Type Puma |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adidas | Type A | Puma | Type B |
| 2 | Adidas | Type C | Puma | Type D |

I am pretty sure this can be done using the `Pivot` function but i have no clue how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm. Found out by myself without using a `PIVOT` function.

```
SELECT
    Id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Brand = 'Adidas' THEN [Brand] END) AS [Brand Adidas], 
    MAX(CASE WHEN Brand = 'Adidas' THEN [Type] END) AS [Type Adidas],
    MAX(CASE WHEN Brand = 'Puma' THEN [Series] END) AS [Brand Puma],
    MAX(CASE WHEN Brand = 'Puma' THEN [Type] END) AS [Type Puma]
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Id
```

Output:

| Id | Brand Adidas | Type Adidas | Brand Puma | Type Puma |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Adidas | Type A | Puma | Type B |
| 2 | Adidas | Type C | Puma | Type D |

Comment: This is known as "conditional aggregation". It something that many prefer to use over the far more restrictive `PIVOT` operator.

Comment: How would you do pivot here?

Comment: I'm not sure on your question, are you asking how I would use `PIVOT`? I'm saying I wouldn't, I don't puld do what you have done.

Comment: oh ok. I git you wrong. Thanks for clarifying!